# Skinny body and strong power simultaneously?

Tags: weight-loss, strength

How Bruce Lee or Ip Man could keep very skinny bodies, but they had very high physical power?

Comment: your answers are very nice, but I can't upvote due to lack of reputation (min. 15)! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly wires and springs. First of all, they weren't as powerful as you see in the movies. But they did indeed have amazing control of their own bodies.

Now, I don't believe Ip Man was especially powerful. Wing Chun was primarily revolved around deflection, and maintaining superior balance while remaining rooted yourself, and Ip Man was especially talented in this.

Bruce Lee, on the other hand, we have footage of, throwing few-inch punches that could knock a man off his feet. The key here is **explosiveness**. But also technique.

Explosiveness is something that is inherent in a lot of the exercise modalities we have. Most exercises can be performed while adding an explosive factor. Athletes like sprinters, high-jumpers and throwers do this all the time, and are able to launch objects/themselves further and higher than anyone else.

Answer (score -1):

I'm gonna answer only your title that is:-

**Skinny body and strong power simultaneously?**

**Strength training** while **eating at a maintainence** (eating at your [TDEE)](http://iifym.com/tdee-calculator/) should allow you to achieve your goal. Incorporating pause work, using bands and chains, speed work and so on. I will not discount calisthenics, but in my opinion, strength training will allow you to be more stronger.

**Unless you are training for a specific martial arts**, why do you want to stay small?